# JavaFX runtime components are missing - Only in a JAR File

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, jar

I'm currently working on a university assignment which requires me to create an application using Java. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA to create this JavaFX application.

I can build and run the application from IntelliJ directly - I've used tutorials such as [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qn2tbftFjno) to help me do so. This allows the application to run perfectly.

However, upon building the JAR file, the application won't load, and throws the following error:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

I can't seem to understand why this would be the case but hoping someone here might know. I've looked around for similar questions - I haven't found one where the error is ONLY when running the JAR file.

I'm using OpenJDK 11 and OpenJFX 11.

Any help provided is much appreciated.

Comment: There are many questions on Stack Overflow with “JavaFX runtime components are missing” in them.

Comment: Correct, each of which talk about the fact they cannot use it within IntelliJ, whereas I can. I can’t use it within a JAR.

Comment: Because JavaFX is not part of Java as of 11, so JavaFX is neither in the Java runtime nor in your .jar file.

Comment: @VGR, I understand that, however, clearly, what I've done so far works for running the application within IntelliJ - this means that it's looking in the right places to run the application. But, when compiled into a .jar, it doesn't work. I've copied the JavaFX .jar files into the Articfacts output layout, yet that doesn't work.

Comment: I expect IntelliJ is doing what those posts state:  adding JavaFX to the module path.  When you run your jar file without any additional module path or classpath settings, you are not doing the same thing IntelliJ is doing.